# webservices arguments instead of parameters

Tags: java, web-services

I'm doing Java-first development on a service and the WSDL file being generated (I'm using Tomcat v6.0 as my container with the CXF Servlet) is using arg0, arg1 etc. as the parameter names for my service methods rather than using the actual parameter name specified in my Java code.  Is this a known shortcoming or am I doing something wrong?  The WSDL isn't very self-documenting with parameter names like this! 
Here's an example wsdl snippet:

```
<xs:complexType name="insertVendor">

<xs:sequence>

  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="xs:string"/>

  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg1" type="xs:string"/>

  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg2" type="xs:string"/>

  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg3" type="xs:string"/>

  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg4" type="xs:string"/>

  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg5" type="xs:string"/>

  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg6" type="xs:string"/>

  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg7" type="xs:string"/>

  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg8" type="xs:string"/>

  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg9" type="xs:string"/>

  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg10" type="xs:string"/>

  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg11" type="xs:string"/>

</xs:sequence>
```

Thanks, 
mallesh

Answer (score 0):

You can create request class and pass it in service method

```
Class Requestclass(){
```

// all the arguments you want, create POJO class

```
}
```

pass this class in your method,

```
insertVendor(RequestClass req){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [answer](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-Thepartsinmygeneratedwsdlhavenamesoftheform%22arg0%22,%22arg1%22,...Whydon%27ttheparts%28andJavageneratedfromthem%29usetheniceparameternamesItypedintotheinterfacedefinition?)

Official answer: The JAX-WS spec (specifically section 3.6.1) mandates that it be generated this way. To customize the name, you have to use an @WebParam(name = "blah") annotation to specify better names. (You can use @WebResult for the return value, but you'll only see the results if you look at the XML.)